# Is it possible to load an image when I press a command without blocking the application?

Tags: image, java-me

How do I load an image without blocking the application at the press of a command?
For normal swing apps, there's the swingworker, is there something like that for J2ME also?

Comment: have you tried using threads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kick off a new thread in your command handler and load the image in that thread.  Or, if you do it a lot, have an Image Loader thread constantly running, which processes a queue of image loading requests, and add a request to that queue in your command handler.